# How to specify concrete type for abstract method param in Jersey/ Jackson?

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am using Jersey and have exposed a resource `Resource` which implements an `Interface`. One of the methods from `Interface` has a parameter `a` of type  `A` which is an abstract class.

Here is some code for explanation:

```
//Interface.java
public interface Interface {
    public void setA(A a);
}
//Resource.java
@Path("/hello")
public class Resource implements Interface {
    @POST
    public void setA(A a){ //Here I want to specify AImpl instead of A
        //Code that uses AImpl
    }
}
//A.java
public abstract class A{
    //Some abstract stuff
}
//AImpl.java
public class AImpl extends A{
    //Some concrete stuff
}
```

This leads to an error:

```
JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of A, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
```

How can this be avoided/ overcome?

One solution would be to make Jersey/Jackson aware that it can use the concrete implementation of `A` (which is `AImpl`) in method `setA()` of `Resource`. Is there any annotation that I can use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered simply making `Interface` generic? Something like

```
public abstract class SuperType {}
```

```
public class SubType extends SuperType {}
```

```
public interface Resource<T extends SuperType> {
    Response doSomething(T type);
}
```

```
@Path("resource")
public class SubTypeResource implements Resource<SubType> {
    @POST
    @Override
    public Response doSomething(SubType type) {
        ...
    } 
}
```